# How are Events aggregated

Tags: frame

I noticed that every pallet (that i've checked) that has any events uses the following line in the pallets config trait:

`type Event: From<Event<Self, I>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;`

Given the use of `From` i'm guessing the Runtime has one huge Event Enum that contains all pallet Event Enums. Is this the case? If so where is this declared in the Runtime as i cannot find it in the node implementation (if done by a Macro, can you provide some background info).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are right that every runtime has `Event` declaration that combines all the events of each pallet. It looks roughly like this:

```
enum Event {
   System(frame_system::Event),
   Balances(pallet_balances::Event),
   ..
}
```

This "overarching" event is generated by the `construct_runtime!` macro.

You will find this concept of "overarching" types quite a lot in Substrate. Another good example is the `Call` enum that is doing the same as the `Event` enum.

When you for example send an event from your custom pallet, it will be first converted to the overarching `Event` of the runtime. This is the reason for the `From` implementation you mentioned above. After that conversion the event is passed to `frame-system` to be stored in a `Vec<Event>` where `Event` is the overarching `Event` of the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you can retrieve `Event`s by querying `system.events` storage with specified blockhash.